WARN: matter-js: Matter.Engine.update: delta argument is recommended to be less than or equal to 16.667 ms
I am using matter-js with react-native-game-engine to create game with a falling body. And then, in setupWorld() function I am defining them, like this:
class GameScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            running: true,
            score: 0
        };

        this.gameEngine = null;

        this.entities = this.setupWorld();
    }
setupWorld = () => {
        let ball= Matter.Bodies.circle(Constants.MAX_WIDTH / 2, Constants.COIN_TOPDIST, 20, { isStatic: false}  )
        ball.collisionFilter = {
            'group': -1,
            'category': 2,
            'mask': 0,
        }
        let engine = Matter.Engine.create({ enableSleeping: false })
        let world = engine.world;
        world.gravity.y = 0.0;

        Matter.World.add(world, body);

        return {
            physics: { engine: engine, world: world },
            ball: { body: ball, renderer: Ball},
        }
}

render () {
return (
                <GameEngine
                    ref={(ref) => { this.gameEngine = ref; }}
                    style={styles.gameContainer}
                    systems={[Physics]}
                    running={this.state.running}
                    onEvent={this.onEvent}
                    entities={this.entities}>
                </GameEngine>
)
}

package.json:
"matter-js": "^0.20.0",  -->latest
"react-native": "0.73.6",
"react-native-game-engine": "^1.2.0", -->latest

The point where I stuck is, I don't use anywhere the function of Matter.Engine.update(engine) but I keep taking this warning in the console:
WARN  matter-js: Matter.Engine.update: delta argument is recommended to be less than or equal to 16.667 ms.  

Should I handle this warning. If yes, how can get rid of it? Any help is really appreciated.
EDIT: I realized now that Matter.Engine.update function is used in Physics.js:
const Physics = (entities, { touches, time, dispatch }) => {
    let engine = entities.physics.engine;
    let world = entities.physics.world;
    let ball= entities.ball.body;

  let hadTouches = false;
  touches.filter(t => t.type === "press").forEach(t => {
    if (!hadTouches){
        if (world.gravity.y === 0.0){
            world.gravity.y = 1.2;
        }

        hadTouches = true;
        Matter.Body.setVelocity( ball, {
            x: ball.velocity.x,
            y: -10
        });
    }

  });

  Matter.Engine.update(engine, time.delta);  // HERE !!
  return entities;
}

export default Physics;

I don't know where this time prop is coming from. If it is a default value of matter.js physics, why this error appears?

Help us help you - share the code the produces this warning

@Mureinik I added the codes. Can you have a look please?

Behavior for the timestep has changed in 0.20.0. Does the warning go away if you downgrade to 0.19.0? The code doesn't seem quite complete--I'm not too familiar with RNGE so I'd have to fiddle for awhile to get something running and it's not clear I'd be able to reproduce the problem even with a fair amount of effort, so if you can share a complete, runnable [mcve] I can look into this easier. Where is Physics.js? I don't see it in either MJS or RNGE source code. BTW, World is deprecated.

@ggorlen There wasn't this warning in 0.19.0, this warning showed up after I upgraded to latest. Can I make it work without a warning in the latest version?

Probably, but I'd need to see the full reproducible code to play with it and investigate. Please see my above comment.

@ggorlen I now updated it, included full code of the Physics.js where the game logic is on touch events

Got it, thanks. Did you try printing the delta value? Maybe try removing the delta? I'm guessing MJS 0.20.0 upgrade has thrown this logic out of sync with RNGL.

@ggorlen I made it work as before by changing time.delta to 16 and setting world.gravity.y to 20 and setVelocity function y value to -40. But I wonder if isn't there another way of hard typing the time.delta value as before just writing as time.delta in engine.update function?

Did you try removing it entirely?

@ggorlen removing it entirely and leaving as Matter.Engine.update(engine) or giving the value of 16 to time.delta  creates the same result, making the popping of ball very very slow, I need to change the values of the gravity force and position then.

Got it, thanks for testing that.

Here's another example: How to user Matter.js in pixi.js project?. If you bump MJS to 0.20.0 you'll see the warning. The delta hovers around 17 for me, just above the threshold in a way that shouldn't impact the animation. I may change that example to use Matter's runner rather than Pixi's runner so if this comment goes stale check the edit history of the linked post.
